# JSonRestStore and CLientfilter

Tags: json, dojo, store

I've setup a little script for testing JRS and a clientfilter. I've used what I could find on the internet to set it up but it ain't working. I'm trying to perform a client side fetch on a JRS using clientFilter. Nevertheless the JRS is querying the backend in stead of performing the fetch clientsided. I pasted the script below, I hope one of you can explain why it isn't working.

Thanks

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/dojo-release-1.7.2/dojo/resources/dojo.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/dojo-release-1.7.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"/>

    <script>
        dojoConfig= {
            has: {
                "dojo-firebug": true
            },
            parseOnLoad: true,
            isDebug: true,
            locale: "nl"
        };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo-release-1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojox.data.ClientFilter");
        dojo.require("dojox.data.JsonRestStore");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

        myStore = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({target:"TARGET"});
        myStore.fetch();

        dojo.ready(function() {
            dojo.connect(dijit.byId("query"), "onClick", function() {
                myStore.fetch({query:{id:"4"},queryOptions:{cache:true}, onItem: function(item) {console.log(item); }});
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body cllass="tundra">
    <button type="button" id="query" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Query</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsfiddle that shows how to do this with the new syntax and dojo stores.
http://jsfiddle.net/SgyYW/

```
require([
"dojo/store/Cache",
"dojo/store/JsonRest",
"dojo/store/Memory",
"dojo/parser",
"dojo/on",
"dojo/ready",
"dijit/form/Button",
"dijit/registry"
],function(Cache,JsonRest,Memory,parser,on,ready,Button,registry){
console.log('x');
var someData = [
    {id:1, name:"One"},
    {id:2, name:"Two"},
    {id:3, name:"Three"},
    {id:4, name:"Four"},
    {id:5, name:"Five"}
];
recToQuery = 4;
// recToQuery = 6; // try one that is not in the cache
var memoryStore = new Memory({data: someData});
var restStore = new JsonRest({ target: "/i/dont/exist.json/"});
var myStore = new Cache(restStore, memoryStore);
myStore.query({}); // this will ask for everything and prime the cache
ready(function(){
    parser.parse();
    var queryBtn = registry.byId("query");
    console.log('queryBtn',queryBtn);
    on(queryBtn, "click", function() {
        console.log('query button clicked',[this,arguments]);
        var resultOrPromise = myStore.get(recToQuery);
        if (typeof resultOrPromise.then ==='function'){
            // it is asking the server
            resultOrPromise.then(function(){
                console.log('Result from server fetch',arguments);
            },function(){
                console.log('it queried the server but failed',arguments);
            });
        }else{
            // it is in the cache (from the first query)
            console.log('result from cache:',resultOrPromise);
        }
    });//end connect
}); //end ready
}); //end require
```

Comment: Thanks, couple of questions why do you use the new syntax, is this due to some known bug with the old syntax? The store itself differs from the one I use, jsonreststore and reststore, unfortunatly for now I'm not able to switch due to the amount of reengineering tthat'll create :(

Comment: You can use them together to ease your transition pain. With dojo 2.0, the support for the old syntax will be dropped. Where I work, we still have many widgets using the old widgets. Old widgets can use new, and new can use old.